# Error executing grub customizer as root

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, password, startup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5ktd.png)I have a dual boot on my laptop. Since my computer had Windows before I installed my Kubuntu, this first OS is the default for startup. Since I did not want it as my default and I wanted to change the default to Ubuntu, I installed Grub Customizer, but whenever I open it requests a password to which I enter my user password of the OS, but it does not accept it. Since I consider it was the root password but the user password, thinking they both are different, I tried changing the root password, but that did not work either.

This is the chart that appears:

[image]

Comment: Since it's not in English, I'm not sure what it says, could you translate it?

Comment: There is a English version now